# Has anyone managed to get ASPNET Core working with Signal R?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-core, signalr

I have followed the example in this article which based on the feedback was working at one point but newer builds seem to have broke.

https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-mvc-signalr/

Any assistance would be great.

**Update 1**

To clarify, I can get the controller to call the method on the view (addpost) but the parameter doesnt seem to be passing, for this example the addpost(post) method gets called but nothing is being passed in the Post variable.

```
 function addPost(post) {
        $("#postsList").append(
                '<li><b>' + post.userName + '</b><br>' + post.text + '</li><br>'
             );
    }
```

Comment: What particular problem do you have, can you describe? Broken build or is something isn't working in logic?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR for ASP.Net Core is being rewritten from ground. The packages from the post are no longer maintained. You can find new SignalR - including samples - in [this repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR). Keep in mind this is a pretty much work in progress and code is rapidly evolving. 
I wrote a couple of posts about the new SignalR which also might be helpful. You can find them here:

- [SignalR Core 1/3: Design considerations](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-13-design-considerations/)
- [SignalR Core 2/3: ASP.Net Core Sockets](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/)

Comment: Could the "old" (.net 4.6) version be used with dotnet core? Or is Signalr unavailible on dotnet core until the rewrite has finished?